# Вложенные маршруты в Rails с помощью одной модели

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь сделать красивые *url* для сайта. Например, `catalog/mebel/`.

Первый уровень вложенности вышло сделать благодаря:

```
def to_param
  url
end
```

А вот сделать маршрут, например, `catalog/mebel/divan` — не выходит. Дело в том, что я использую для хранения информации об этих разделах одну модель, а родителя у раздела определяю графой `parent_id`. При сборке маршрута как `url родителя/url потомка` выходит, что *rails* преобразует `/` в код `%2F`.

Есть ли возможность обойти это? Или нужно разбивать каждый уровень на новую модель? Последнее пока отметаю, так как не хочется излишнего дублирования.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо сложностей и лишних гемов. Можно решить просто с помощью роута:

```
get 'catalog(/:category_name(/:item_name))' => 'catalog#show'
```

В итоге, в контроллере **Catalog** в методе **show** имеем **params** такого вида:

```
{
  "controller"    => "catalog", 
  "action"        => "show", 
  "category_name" => "mebel", 
  "item_name"     => "divan"
}
```

Скармливаем это методу модели, который вернёт нам товар(ы) основываясь на ключах **category_name** и **item_name**. Вложенность получается жёсткая, но зато всё просто и, возможно, достаточно для решения вашей задачи.